# Using python looping to call multiple SQL databases

Tags: python, loops

I want to call multiple databases in Microsoft SQL:

```
driver = 'SQL Server'
server = '123'
tcon = 'yes'
uname = 'name'
pword = 'password'
query = "query1"
```

I make my databases into list as below:

```
db = ['DBA','DBB','DBC']
```

Then execute looping to call all databases in the list above as below:

```
for i in db:
  sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host=server, database= f'{i}',
                  trusted_connection=tcon, user=uname, password=pword)

  df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)

  df['DB_NAME'] = f'{i}' #to add name column in the dataframe
```

However, i only get data from 'DBC'. I want three separate dataframes such as df_DBA, df_DBB, df_DBC from the looping above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop, `df` is overwriten with a new dataframe. So it will hold data from the last iteration of the loop, which is from `DBC` since it is the last in the list.

If you want separate variables for data from each database, try this:

```py
def read_sql(query, db_name):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host=server, database=db_name,
                          trusted_connection=tcon, user=uname, password=pword)
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    df['DB_NAME'] = db_name
    return df


db_DBA = read_sql(query, 'DBA')
db_DBB = read_sql(query, 'DBB')
db_DBC = read_sql(query, 'DBC')
```